# NSInvocationOperation and NSOperationQueue concurrency

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

I am using `NSInvocationOperation` with `NSOperationQueue` developing in iOS5.
According to apple documentation on **invocation objects**:

> The NSInvocationOperation class is a concrete subclass of
>   NSOperation... This class implements a **non-concurrent** operation.

Ok, so my `NSInvocationOperation` object executes synchronously? (correct me here) Apple's docs also says on operation queue objects:

> In iOS, operation queues do not use Grand Central Dispatch to execute
>   operations. They create separate threads for non-concurrent operations
>   and launch concurrent operations from the current thread.

I am using the `NSInvocationObject`, which is a non-concurrent object, and adding it to to the operation queue like so:

```
[operationQueue addOperation:operation];
```

so my question is: 1) Since the operation queue will be spawning a separate thread to execute the NSInvocationObject as it says in the docs, will it be run asynchronously instead of synchronously?

**[UPDATE - in response to Dani's answer below. Taken from an [Apple link](https://developer.apple.com/cocoa/managingconcurrency.html).**

> NSOperation and NSOperationQueue
>
> There are a number of different ways that you can use NSOperation, but
>   the most common is to write a custom subclass and override one method:
>   main. The main method gets called to perform the operation when the
>   NSOperationQueue schedules it to run. NSOperation classes written in
>   this way are known as non-concurrent operations, because the developer
>   is not responsible for spawning threads—multi-threading is all handled
>   by the super class. **(Don’t be confused by the terminology: just
>   because an operation is non-concurrent, does not mean it cannot be
>   executed concurrently, it simply means that you don't have to handle
>   the concurrency yourself.)**
>
> If you need more control over threading and the run-time environment
>   of your operations, you can make use of concurrent operations. To do
>   this, you subclass NSOperation and override the start method. In the
>   start method, you can spawn threads and setup the environment before
>   calling the main method. You are also required to maintain the state
>   of the NSOperation by setting properties like isExecuting and
>   isFinished. In short, concurrent operations give you a lot more
>   control, but also demand more effort—for most tasks non-concurrent
>   operations suffice.

Comment: Concurrent in the sense of the "isConcurrent" flag on NSOperations is a curious and somewhat misleading term. It is used consistently and vaguely makes sense in the context, but it may not mean what you expect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you add it to an operation queue it will run asynchronously with respect to the rest of your code, but synchronously on the operation queue.
It's pretty much like:

```
With synchronous objects:

Creating thread
    |
    |\
    | \______
    |        |
    |       Operation A
    |        |
    |       Operation B
    |        |
    |        |

With asynchronous objects:

Creating thread
    |
    |\
    | \___________________
    |                     |
    |\                  Operation A
    | \______             |
    |        |            |
    |       Operation B   |
    |        |            |
    |        |            |
```

Comment: Thanks man. Seems like ascii diagrams made it so much simpler than the the verbose docs ^^,

Comment: needed one small clarification about your diagram.  Adding the synchronous NSInvocationOperation object to the NSOperationQueue makes it function like the first diagram? And if that is the case, will this be functioning like a serial queue?